# JointsWP4 (SASS): Changing Properties in Sticky

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

**TL;DR: Is Sticky actually able to react to changes I give through JavaScript? If so, how?**

*(The project is using Foundation 6.2 and WordPress 4.4, theme installed using Node.js/npm and gulp 4.0. My questions, in detail, are marked in bold print.)*

I want to make the `nav` bar sticky using Foundation's Sticky Plugin, but only when I click on a button. That means that when the DOM is all finished, the `nav` bar shouldn't stick "by itself", but stay in its top position in the document. *Additionally,* it should disappear when scrolling down, but stick while scrolling up.

The `nav` bar is correctly wrapped in all the required `div`s, so the `nav` bar is able to stick. The problems arise with the "additionally" part. My idea was to instantiate Sticky using PHP first:

```
<div data-sticky-container>
  <header class="header" role="banner" id="sticky_header" data-sticky data-top-anchor="1" 
    data-btm-anchor="content:top" data-options="marginTop:0;" style="width:100%"
>
    <?php get_template_part('parts/nav', 'offcanvas-topbar'); ?>
  </header>
</div>
```

After that, change the `data-btm-anchor` to the current scroll position using JavaScript that's fired off on click. This did not work as well as I'd like. What I've tried so far:

1. When using `getElementByID` and then `setAttribute`, the `data-btm-anchor` in the PHP file does change according to Firebug, but that doesn't influence the `nav` bar a bit; it stays where it is. **Do I need to "reinstantiate" Sticky, and if so, how?**
2. The [docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html) mention:

> Setting options with JavaScript involves passing an object into the constructor function, like this:
>
> ```
> var options = {
>    multiExpand: true,
>    allowAllClosed: false
> };
> var accordion = new Foundation.Accordion($('#some-accordion'), options);
> ```

**Does that mean I can pass *new parameters* to an already existing plugin instance?** Whenever I passed a new `Foundation.Sticky` object with nothing more than a differing *btmAnchor* as my options array parameter to my `jQuery('#sticky_header')`, nothing happened.

3. The [docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html) also propose programmatically adding Sticky to my "sticky_header". If that worked, I could try to directly alter the jQuery object. So far I have been able to bind the Sticky plugin to my header successfully by:

   1. throwing the .js from which the button gets its function into `assets/js/scripts` (and then running `gulp`)
   2. deleting all the data-sticky tags from my `<header class="header">`, so there's no sticky plugin registered to the header when the DOM has finished loading
   3. programmatically adding the plugin:

      ```
      function button_fire(){
        var options = {
          topAnchor:"1",
          btmAnchor:"footer:top",
          marginTop:"1"
        };
        var stick = new Foundation.Sticky(jQuery('.header'), options);
      }
      ```

   The header now gains the "sticky" class according to Firebug. But it still doesn't work - rather, it glitches: The "header space" is somewhat collapsed so it's slightly covering the "content" `div` below. What do you know, the header doesn't stick. Is that a bug?

   Suppose it would work "brilliantly" now, **am I theoretically able to change attributes by dereferencing `var stick` or using `jQuery('#sticky_header')` or `jQuery('.header')`?**

Above all of this, jQuery doesn't work as it should. I've had a lot of problems with using **`$`** in my scripts, and I can't, for instance, run the `destroy()` method of Sticky because of this (if it worked, I may have destroyed an instance of Sticky to make a new one with the `btmAnchor` set to a new scrolling position). I'll open another question for this.

Comment: Have you enqueued jQuery?

Comment: Upon searching, there is actually no wp_enqueue_script() function call that explicitly enqueues jQuery, so now I did that by writing in assets/functions/enqueue-scripts.php:

    `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );`

Still the same problem as before, unfortunately. Or did I enqueue jQuery incorrectly? Does JointsWP have some jQuery libs of its own?

Comment: WordPress automatically enqueues jQuery, no need to enqueue it on your own. Also, "jQuery" is correct - but $ should still work. WordPress runs jQuery in no conflict mode, which is why "jQuery" is used instead of $.

Comment: So does that mean writing "jQuery" instead of "$" is the preferred way to do it and it should work in the same way? (I'm new to jQuery) *(also, great work on JointsWP, Jeremy! :) Absolutely love it.)*

Comment: @SamuelLOLHackson, you could also use "$" in WordPress, however, either you have to speciffically assign jQuery to it like this: `var $ = jQuery`, 
or pass it on calling .ready() method like this: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ //your code here with using $ or jQuery });`

Comment: for the "scrolling up" question, you could change the `top` in css to negative. so it moves off the screen but is still "stuck".  `top : -heightOfNav`

Comment: I am very surprised, I had a question and leave 500 bounty for answering, and reach the true and complete answer, this question is for 2 years ago and has no bounty. thanks for your kind.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the sticky css attribute in your scss.

In html or php add class to your component:

```
<div data-sticky-container class="sticky-container">
```

and in scss or css:

```
.sticky-container {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10; 
}
```

Now just put the distance from top you need!

Answer (score 0):

Prefer controlling the sticky by using jquery completely.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('<Your button>').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('<where you want to go>').offset().top}, 1000);
    });
```

Using this you can make a button scroll you to any part of your website.

For the sticky, you want to add the sticky class only when you scroll past the first section so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(<Section name after which you want sticky to appear>).waypoint(function(direction){
        if (direction == "down"){
           $('nav').addClass('sticky');
           }else{
               $('nav').removeClass('sticky');
           }
    }, {
        offset: '60px'
    });

});
```

Using the waypoints plugin, you can now easily add the sticky class when you scroll past an element or section. Jquery selector can select by id and class using # and . respectively.

Answer (score -1):

If you use wordpress, it enqueues JQuery automatically.

You have two ways to use JQuery in Wordpress.

**Use JQuery instead $**

Wordpress runs JQuery in his no conflict mode so you have to use Jquery instead $

Your Case

```
var options = {
   multiExpand: true,
   allowAllClosed: false
};
var accordion = new Foundation.Accordion(JQuery('#some-accordion'), options);
```

**Use $ like a variable**

You can also use $ but you have to define a variable like this :

```
var options = {
   multiExpand: true,
   allowAllClosed: false
};
var accordion = new Foundation.Accordion($('#some-accordion'), options);
```